# Laravel Routes::post returning 500 Internal Error after enabling SSL

Tags: laravel

I have a problem
All of post request after ssl using don't work.(
result of all post request is

500 Internal Error
The server encountered an internal error and could not complete your request.

`Route::post('check','HDRController@check'); 
Route::post('sprawdz_csa','HDRController@sprawdz_csa');
Route::post('rejestracja_abonenta','HDRController@rejestracja_abonenta');
Route::get('zamow_domene', array('as' => 'zamow_domene', 'uses' => 'HomeController@domena_get'));
//Route::get('zamow_domene','HomeController@domena_get');
Route::post('kontakt',array('as' => 'kontakt', 'uses' => 'HomeController@kontakt'));`

Comment: What do your logs say?  Also, please review [guidelines for asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help us get you the best answer.

Comment: Would like please share a little of code? if it is posible, make the simple example

Comment: after submitting every form has 500 error,

Comment: How have you enabled the ssl? through laravel or server?

Comment: enabled on the server